# Android: firebase Dynamic Link issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

How to get data from dynamic link when i am trying to get data and link using following method i get error.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) 
                 {

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

getting can not resolve  `addOnSuccessListener()` error.

Comment: Try clean & rebuild your project if you are using android studio.

Comment: already did that but com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-15.0.1 not in my external libs so how to add it